Get CRC of all files and folders with 7z
Using the 7-zip cmd-line like this:
7z l -slt <zipfile>
Generate a detailed list of all the folders and files in the zipfile, but strangely the CRC does not appear for the folders, but only for the files.
Is it possible to retrieve also the CRC of folders somehow?
In the GUI they appear..

You are right, but the CRC of the data folder (which contains files and therefore data) is shown in 7zip classical GUI, I don't understand why the same thing isn't shown when you run "7z -l <archive.zip> -slt", a + appears next to the folders and there's nothing under the "CRC=" entry

I just checked it the 7-zip UI 24.08 does not show a CRC value for directories in zip files, it only shows them for directories in 7z files (and the crc changes if you delete a file in that folder).
